# deleteing matching values from table1 when found in table2

Tags: mysql

i am a newbie and i cannot write a subquery.i have two table one `csv` and other is `master`.i want to delete records from `csv` where `values` present in `master`.

my `csv` table

```
id(PK)    phone
1         1234
2         2345
3         7777
```

my `master` table

```
urn    phone
1      9988
2      1234
3      7777
```

to find the values present in csv and master i query.

```
select phone from csv where phone in (select phone from master)

  phone
  1234
  7777
```

now how can i delete the matching values from csv in a single query from php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you can replace the `select` with `delete from`:

```
delete from csv
    where phone in (select phone from master);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
delete csv
from csv
join master on csv.phone = master.phone
```